# Limiting Gitea logins to members of groups with specific role

Tags: ldap

I have an LDAP server (OpenBSD 7.1 running the native `ldapd` service) setup with the following DIT entries:

```
dn: uid=nick.chambers,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: nick.chambers
cn: Nick Chambers
sn: Chambers
homeDirectory: /home/nick.chambers
displayName: uplime
loginShell: /bin/sh
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 10000
shadowExpire: 0
userPassword:: e0NSWVBUfSQyYiQxMCRwTHFkM1hnSlNVQWRHR1JoRTNESlVlSHAvc3FLSmgyTVp
 oL2JRUG1wNlh5aEs1RXEyMFBCNg==

dc=spookyinternet,dc=com '(objectClass=groupOfNames)'
dn: cn=sysadmins,ou=public,ou=groups,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=co
 m
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: sysadmins
member: uid=nick.chambers,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinte
 rnet,dc=com

dn: cn=git,ou=roles,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: git
description: Allows using git as a normal user
roleOccupant: cn=sysadmins,ou=public,ou=groups,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinte
 rnet,dc=com
```

So, `nick.chambers` is a member of the `sysadmins` group which in turn has the role `git`. Using this sample setup, I want to limit gitea logins to users who are in a group that has the `git` role. I can make a filter to test if a group has a role, and to test if a user is a member of a group, but have no idea how to combine them. Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP doesn't have a built-in way to perform such checks in a single search. (It could be done custom by an implementation – e.g. Active Directory has a few "extensible match" operators, one of which supports recursively following member/memberOf links – but OpenBSD ldapd does not implement any such extensions.)

So you'd probably need to hack Gitea to perform multiple LDAP lookups, one to list the user's group membership, one to retrieve all roleOccupants.

---

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! An alternative way that I was considering was in addition to adding groups to roles, also add the role to the groups, and then I can filter on objectClass. Would there be a problem with a structure like that?